# Springboot Hibernate does not create tables in remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to create tables on my remote db, but It doesn't make any query on it.
Actually when I'm typing my db password wrong it gives me an error, so I assume that somehow it is connecting but not serializing any entity.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<groupId>com.palmieri</groupId>
<artifactId>InstaPalm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>InstaPalm</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my entity class User

```
package com.palmieri.InstaPalm.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;
@Entity
@Table(name = "photo")
public class Photo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6470094278127188729L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
private Date data;
@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private User user;
@Column(name="link", nullable = false)
private String link;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "photo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Like> likes;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "photo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Comment> comments;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Date data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public List<Like> getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(List<Like> likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}

public List<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
}
```

And my application.properties

```
## Database Properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://sql2.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/XXX?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = XXXXX
spring.datasource.password = XXXXX
## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

I'm sure i'm missing some configuration or some property but I cant figure out which one, maybe I mismatched the packages? thank you for your response

**EDIT 1**
Here is my log

```
2020-09-23 14:54:49.807  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.InstaPalm.InstaPalmApplication       : Starting InstaPalmApplication on SI-W-00446 with PID 14620 (C:\Users\SI2001\IdeaProjects\InstaPalm\InstaPalm\target\classes started by SI2001 in C:\Users\SI2001\IdeaProjects\InstaPalm\InstaPalm)
2020-09-23 14:54:49.809  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.InstaPalm.InstaPalmApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-23 14:54:49.809 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.palmieri.InstaPalm.InstaPalmApplication
2020-09-23 14:54:49.919 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/C:/Users/SI2001/IdeaProjects/InstaPalm/InstaPalm/target/classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2020-09-23 14:54:49.921 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/SI2001/IdeaProjects/InstaPalm/InstaPalm/target/classes/]
2020-09-23 14:54:49.921 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.settings.DevToolsSettings        : Included patterns for restart : []
2020-09-23 14:54:49.921 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.settings.DevToolsSettings        : Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-starter/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-devtools/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-actuator/(bin|build|out)/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/(bin|build|out)/]
2020-09-23 14:54:49.922  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-09-23 14:54:49.922  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-09-23 14:54:49.922 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4d5a23dd
2020-09-23 14:54:51.024  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-09-23 14:54:51.046  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-09-23 14:54:51.574 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\SI2001\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.3.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar
2020-09-23 14:54:51.575 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\SI2001\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.3.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar
2020-09-23 14:54:51.575 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
2020-09-23 14:54:51.641  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-23 14:54:51.651  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-23 14:54:51.651  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-09-23 14:54:51.797  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-23 14:54:51.798 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2020-09-23 14:54:51.798  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1876 ms
2020-09-23 14:54:51.927 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: filterRegistrationBean urls=[/*] order=-2147483647, characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105
2020-09-23 14:54:51.927 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/]
2020-09-23 14:54:51.945 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.m.w.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter  : Filter 'webMvcMetricsFilter' configured for use
2020-09-23 14:54:51.945 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use
2020-09-23 14:54:51.945 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use
2020-09-23 14:54:51.945 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedFormContentFilter     : Filter 'formContentFilter' configured for use
DEBUG StatusLogger org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory is not on classpath. Good!
2020-09-23 14:54:52.109  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-23 14:54:52.147  INFO 14620 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-23 14:54:52.200  INFO 14620 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2020-09-23 14:54:52.355  INFO 14620 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-23 14:54:52.361 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-09-23 14:54:52.415 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2020-09-23 14:54:52.446 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2020-09-23 14:54:52.459 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2020-09-23 14:54:52.463  INFO 14620 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-23 14:54:53.132  INFO 14620 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-09-23 14:54:53.153  INFO 14620 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-09-23 14:54:53.364 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application Admin MBean registered with name 'org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication'
2020-09-23 14:54:53.411 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.livereload.LiveReloadServer      : Starting live reload server on port 35729
2020-09-23 14:54:53.413  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-09-23 14:54:53.419  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-09-23 14:54:53.479  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-23 14:54:53.481  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-09-23 14:54:53.482  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-09-23 14:54:53.500  INFO 14620 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.InstaPalm.InstaPalmApplication       : Started InstaPalmApplication in 4.246 seconds (JVM running for 5.36)
2020-09-23 14:54:53.506 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]
2020-09-23 14:54:53.506 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Immediately restarting application
2020-09-23 14:54:53.506 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@1c3d316b
2020-09-23 14:54:53.506 DEBUG 14620 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Starting application com.palmieri.InstaPalm.InstaPalmApplication with URLs [file:/C:/Users/SI2001/IdeaProjects/InstaPalm/InstaPalm/target/classes/]
2020-09-23 14:54:54.064  INFO 14620 --- [ion(3)-10.8.2.7] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-23 14:54:54.064  INFO 14620 --- [ion(3)-10.8.2.7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-23 14:54:54.064 DEBUG 14620 --- [ion(3)-10.8.2.7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-09-23 14:54:54.071 DEBUG 14620 --- [ion(3)-10.8.2.7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-09-23 14:54:54.072  INFO 14620 --- [ion(3)-10.8.2.7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
```

Comment: I solved it, it was a relationship problem, check your Entities before running everything

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your purpose by adding this

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

**But keep in mind that, everytime you start your application, it will delete all previous tables and data. So to avoid this, you just change it to`update` like this**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: any error on your console?  or is any generated query?
Also, please check if there is any related database too, if there clean deleting them

Comment: I didn't recieve any error or any query, that's why i think there might be some dependency problem

Answer (score 0):

add `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` to your db.url

```
   spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://sql2.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/XXX useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Comment: I used it but it didn't change anything, in the console I can only read _org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect_ about Hibernate and nothing else

Comment: Could that be something about my sqlDialect?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use the following configurations in application.properties/application.yml file:

```
database:
  name: yourdbname
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: ######
    password: ######
    url: jdbc:mysql://sql2.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/${database.name}&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Hibernate to create your tables you should set the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto Property in your application.property file from none to create or update.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It's better to create an empty database first using the SQL command if it's not available in your MySQL server.
2. Then run your application with the following property added into your application.properties file.

   `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`

As the update parameter will not drop your database and recreate it on each restart